# Parameterization of the initial condition of nonlinear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, parametric, parametrization

(NOTE: I am not asking for the solution to this PDE)

I have the PDE,
$$u_x u_y + ln(x^2)=0,$$
with the condition that,
$$u(x_0,y)=y,$$
where $x_0$ is a constant. I am to find the explicit solution (using Charpit's equations).
In order to do this I first need to parameterize the initial condition in the form of a curve $\Gamma (s)$ in order to solve.

I am used to parameterizing curves but not of this type.

I have written down, 
$$u=s, x=x_0, y=s,$$
just as a hunch but I have no working to show for it.
Is this correct? How do you parameterize equations of this type?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: does $\ln(x^2) = 2\ln(x)$ help at all

Comment: @phdmba7of12 maybe; when solving the equation. Not for the parameterization. Solving the PDE becomes fairly trivial once I have the parameterization.

Comment: what specific text are you referring to describing this method

Comment: a precedent exists here on the stack https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674756/charpit-method-non-linear-pde

Comment: @phdmba7of12 I'm asking how to parameterize the initial condtion, not how to solve the PDE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct parameterisation is 
$$u=s, y=s, x=x_0$$
This leads to a solution through Charpit's method of 
$$u=-2xln(x)+2x+2x_0ln(x_0)-2x_0+y$$