# Solving a tricky PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

We are required to solve the PDE $$p^2 + q^2 = z^2(x+y)$$

Where $p \equiv z_{x}, q \equiv z_{y}$.

I tried using the charpit equations, although couldn't think of anything that would produce a solution..

Next, I tried using the transformations $X=x+y, Y=x-y, P=z_{X}= p+q, Q=z_{Y}=p-q$, which gave the equation:

$$(P^2+Q^2)= z^2X/2$$

The charpit equations read:

$$ \dfrac{dX}{2P}=\dfrac{dY}{2Q}=\dfrac{dZ}{2(P^2+Q^2)}(\equiv \dfrac{dz}{z^2X})=\dfrac{dP}{z^2/2+zPX}=\dfrac{dQ}{zQX}$$

Using the 3rd and the 5th terms, we can see that $$dQ/Q=dz/z$$
S0, $Q=az$.

But apart from this, I dont see any other terms giving something useful.. So how exactly do we approach this question?

Comment: This is just a more nonlinear version of the [Eikonal equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eikonal_equation). The Charpit method should work, you can follow a similar example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2674756/charpit-method-non-linear-pde). It might be easier to rewrite the equations as \begin{align} z_{x}^{2}+z_{y}^{2} &= (x+y)z^{2} \\ \implies \left( \frac{z_{x}}{z} \right)^{2}+\left( \frac{z_{y}}{z} \right)^{2}&=(x+y) \\ \implies (\partial_{x} \ln z)^{2}+(\partial_{y} \ln z)^{2}&=(x+y) \\ \implies u_{x}^{2}+u_{y}^{2}&=(x+y) \quad \text{(where $u=\ln z$)} \end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$$(z_x)^2+(z_y)^2=(x+y)z^2$$
Without boundary condition the solution is undefinite (they are an infinity of solutions).

For example one can look for solutions on the form $z(X)$ with $X=x+y$ :

$z_x=z_y=z'(X)\quad\implies\quad 2(z')^2=X\:z^2\quad\implies\quad\frac{z'}{z}=\pm\sqrt{\frac12 X}\quad\implies\quad z=c\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} X^{3/2}} $
$$\boxed{z(x,y)=c\:e^{\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} (x+y)^{3/2}}} $$
$c$ is an arbitrary constant.

The Charpit equations leads to the same result.